# how to show and hide validation message using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In following code if I select only MonthDropdown value and not YearDropdown it should show a validation message.

If I select YearDropdown value and not MonthDropdown value, it should show a validation message.

If I select both dropdown value, the message should be hidden.

I tried myself but I couldn't get the correct result.

```
<div class="field field--with-dropdown clearfix" style="height: 50px;">
    <label for="field-country" >Expiry date</label>
    <div class="select--half" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x=>x.ExpiryMonth).BindTo(months).Events(x => x.Change("checkout.onMonthYearDDlChange")).DataValueField("Value").DataTextField("Text").OptionLabel("Valid Till Month").HtmlAttributes(new{ required = "required", data_required_msg = " Expiry Month is Required",@class="expmonth" })
        @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.ExpiryYear).BindTo(years).Events(x=>x.Change("checkout.onMonthYearDDlChange")).DataValueField("Value").DataTextField("Text").OptionLabel("Valid Till Year").HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required", data_required_msg = " Expiry date is Required", @class = "expyear"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.ExpiryMonth, "", new { @class = "text-danger expmonth",id="expirymonth" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ExpiryYear, "", new { @class = "text-danger", id = "expiryyear" })
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
    span#expirymonth {
    display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Javascript

```
var expMonth = $("#Billing_ExpiryMonth").val();
var expYear = $("#Billing_ExpiryYear").val();

if (expMonth !== "" && expYear !== "") {
    $("#expiryyear").hide();
} else {
    $("#expiryyear").show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using jQuery Validate ?

Comment: am using Kedno and MVC validation just only show and hide purpose i am using javascript this code is runing in Browser Console while open browser press F12.
but this am writing inside of script tag i am not getting correct result.

Comment: I tried this also 
$("span#expiryyear").hide();
$('#expiryyear').attr('style', 'display:none !important');
but this one also not valid for me.
am not getting correct result.

Comment: Have u tried adding your code in Document.Ready()?